# can msbuild resolve wildcard expressions resulting from a transform?

Tags: msbuild

I expected the code below to result in identical items for List and List2 (I have a single cpp1 project in the searched path).

```
<ItemGroup>
    <src Include="cpp1"/>
    <List Include="@(src -> '..\..\..\projects\**\%(identity).vcxproj')" />
    <List2 Include="..\..\..\projects\**\cpp1.vcxproj" />
 </ItemGroup>
```

But what I get is:

```
List: ..\..\..\projects\**\cpp1.vcxproj
List2: ..\..\..\projects\common\cpp1\cpp1.vcxproj
```

So it looks like the wildcard expression is not being expanded when its the result of a transform. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3):

You can get the extra transformation, but you need to add an additional item array, and it needs to have each potential element added one at a time, with a dependent target.  You also need to pass the intermediate item specification through a property,

```
<ItemGroup>
   <src Include="cpp1"/>
   <List1a Include="@(src -> '..\..\..\projects\**\%(Identity).vcxproj')" />
   <List2 Include="..\..\..\projects\**\cpp1.vcxproj" />
</ItemGroup>

<Target Name="TransformWithWildcards"
   Outputs="%(List1a.Identity)">
   <PropertyGroup>
      <_ThisList1a>@(List1a)</_ThisList1a>
   </PropertyGroup>
   <ItemGroup>
      <List1b Include="$(_ThisList1a)" />
   </ItemGroup>
</Target>

<Target Name="Transform"
   DependsOnTargets="TransformWithWildcards">
   <Message Text="1a. %(List1a.Identity)" />
   <Message Text="1b. %(List1b.Identity)" />
   <Message Text="2. %(List2.Identity)" />
</Target>
```

@(List1a) is the same as your original @(List), and @(List1b) contains the results you expected, after TransformWithWildcards completes.

Comment: thanks again. I suppose there is no way to do this without using a target? I would like to have visual studio load this project and show me the value of the item list without having to invoke a target.

Comment: There is a bug in MSBuild, if you use a wildcard (or maybe it's just the recursive ** wildcard), the path can't start with "." so as far as I know you need dynamic execution in the target to get past the bug.  Notice that if you move List1b to the global group, and define it as Include="@(List1a)" it won't work.

Comment: Brian, isn't this answer of yours  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7268040/transform-itemgroup-into-another-itemgroup-with-wildcards also fits to the OP's question? The workaround presented there looks more graceful to me.

Comment: Yes @user835103, that answer is showing the dynamic execution I mentioned in the comment above.  There might still be a tweak needed to get around the bug, notice how in that answer the paths don't start with "." (I'm pretty sure this has been fixed in Dev11)