# transform itemgroup into another itemgroup with wildcards

Tags: xml, msbuild

I have a list of directories defined inside a target:

```
<Target>
  <ItemGroup>
    <FooDirs Include="Foo\Dir1" />
    <FooDirs Include="Foo\Dir2" />
  </ItemGroup>
<Target>
```

Now I want to create list of all files inside `@(FooDirs)`:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <FooFiles Include="@(FooDirs -> '%(Identity)\**\*')" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Which unfortunately does not work, resulting list contains literal strings: `"Foo\Dir1\**\*;Foo\Dir2\**\*"`.
However, if I use deprecated `<CreateItem>` task it works fine:

```
<CreateItem Include="@(FooDirs -> '%(Identity)\**\*')">
  <Output TaskParameter="Include" ItemName="FooFiles" />
</CreateItem>
```

Is this a bug or am I missing something ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this instead, it will properly create FooFiles using task batching:

```
<Target Name="Foo"> 
   <ItemGroup> 
      <FooDirs Include="Foo\Dir1" /> 
      <FooDirs Include="Foo\Dir2" /> 
   </ItemGroup> 
   <ItemGroup> 
      <FooFiles Include="%(FooDirs.Identity)\**\*" />
   </ItemGroup> 
   <Message Text="%(FooFiles.Identity)" />
</Target>
```

(Excerpted from the book "MSBuild Trickery" trick #5)

Comment: Unfortunately it blocks for a while and then dies with OutOfMemoryException.

Comment: Scratch that, it works! I forgot `.Identity` which caused expansion to `\**`.
Sadly, using ItemGroups is still a serious PITA due to other problems. MSBuild is probably the worst build system ever designed.

Comment: I've marked this as an answer though it still would be nice to know why transform does not work (and if it is a bug - I think I saw something on MSDN saying that both forms should be equivalent).